# spring-boot + tomcat RewriteValve

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to somehow customize embedded tomcat with [RewriteValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)? As I can see in [api](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html) there are currently only methods for [addContextValves](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html#addContextValves-org.apache.catalina.Valve...-) and [addEngineValves](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html#addEngineValves-org.apache.catalina.Valve...-) but as pointed tomcat in documentation, RewriteValve should be placed in Host or in a webapp's context.xml. I don't understand if `addContextValves` could work for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. These are two steps you need to follow:

1. Implement your own TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean and set up the RewriteValve

   ```
     import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;  
     ...
     import org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve; 
     ... 

     @Bean TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
       TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
       factory.setPort(8080);
       factory.addContextValves(new RewriteValve());
       return factory;
     }
   ```
2. Add a rewrite.conf file to the WEB-INF directory of your application and specify the rewrite rules. Here is an example rewrite.conf content, which I'm using in the angular application to take advantage of the angular's PathLocationStrategy (basicly I redirect everything to the index.html as we just use spring boot to serve the static web content):

   ```
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(bmp|css|gif|htc|html?|ico|jpe?g|js|pdf|png|swf|txt|xml|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|map)$
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
   ```

Comment: Where do we have to put `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` beside of `main` perhaps?